# Opencv Mat's element indexing producing garbage

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I'm collecting a bunch of pixel along an edge and saving them in a matrix.

```
    cv::Mat vals = cv::Mat(18,7,img.type(),cv::Scalar(0));

    for (int j=1; j<7; j++)
    {
      cv::Point2f coords = start + direction*(step_size*j) - 3*normal;
      cv::Point2f coords_successive = coords + direction - 3*normal;
      cv::Point2f coords_previous = coords - direction - 3*normal;

      for (int y=0; y<7; y++)
      {
        vals.at<int>((j-1)*3, y) = 1;    //this->sample(img, coords_previous+=normal);
        vals.at<int>((j-1)*3+1, y) = 1;  //this->sample(img, coords+=normal);
        vals.at<int>((j-1)*3+2, y) = 1;  //this->sample(img, coords_successive+=normal);
      }

    }

    std::cout << "----" << std::endl;

    for (int x=0; x<18; x++)
    {
        for (int y=0; y<7; y++) 
        {
            std::cout << vals.at<int>(x,y) << "\t";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

Result:

1   1   1   1   1   257 256 
256 256 256 65792   65536   65536   65536
65536   16842752    16777216    16777216    16777216    16777216    16777216
1   1   1   1   1   257 256 
256 256 256 65792   65536   65536   65536
65536   16842752    16777216    16777216    16777216    16777216    16777216
1   1   1   1   1   257 256 
256 256 256 65792   65536   65536   65536
65536   16842752    16777216    16777216    16777216    16777216    16777216
1   1   1   1   1   257 256 
256 256 256 65792   65536   65536   65536
65536   16842752    16777216    16777216    16777216    16777216    16777216
1   1   1   1   1   257 256 
256 256 256 65792   65536   65536   65536
65536   16842752    16777216    16777216    16777216    16777216    16777216
1   1   1   1   1   1   1
256 256 256 256 256 0   1
65536   65536   65536   0   256 0   1

I've already tried:
1) uchar instead of int, as suggested in other posts when working with gray scale images, 
2) using a int[][] matrix (which is working!) and passing the data to the matrix (which is producing the same garbage) 
3) inverting indices (I thought "ok, maybe it's me taking values where the matrix is not defined) but...same garbage.

Comment: welcome to row-col world ;) (please swap your (x,y) in your at() functions)

Comment: also, `vals.at<int>` is most probably the wrong type. you have to use the Mat's type here, you're not free to choose arbitrary types.

Comment: @berak done, same result. 
if the function returns int, what should I use in the cv::Mat?

Comment: the other way round. if your image is uchar, use vals.at<uchar>, if it is 24bit color, use vals.at<Vec3b>  . last, but not least, writing per pixel-loops is definitely **not** the opencv way. what are you trying to achieve ? a simple call to Sobel() might do.

Comment: cannot do differently, the function "sample" takes one coordinate at the time, and I'm not allowed to change that function. Besides, I tried to use uchar: not working.

Comment: e,g. just use: `cout << vals << endl;` to print it

Comment: what is the value of img.type()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing row and columns while printing the mat structure. You can use the following code. if your image is 8UC1 channel, you have to access using uchar like. vals.at(i,j). But you havent specified what is img.type()is. I am assuming it is CV_8UC1

```
 cv::Mat vals = cv::Mat(18,7,img.type(),cv::Scalar(0));

for (int j=1; j<7; j++)
{
  cv::Point2f coords = start + direction*(step_size*j) - 3*normal;
  cv::Point2f coords_successive = coords + direction - 3*normal;
  cv::Point2f coords_previous = coords - direction - 3*normal;

  for (int y=0; y<7; y++)
  {
    vals.at<int>((j-1)*3, y) = 1;    //this->sample(img, coords_previous+=normal);
    vals.at<int>((j-1)*3+1, y) = 1;  //this->sample(img, coords+=normal);
    vals.at<int>((j-1)*3+2, y) = 1;  //this->sample(img, coords_successive+=normal);
  }

}

std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
int rows=vals.rows;
int colms=vals.cols;
for (int x=0; x<rows; x++)
{
    for (int y=0; y<colms; y++) 
    {
        std::cout << vals.at<uchar>(x,y) << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cv:Scalar` is usually of type `double`.

And the first index  is usually the row and the second is the column. This is usual in image processing